# How to Determine if Group A is Significantly Better than Group B

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, inference, ab-test

**Edit: Please Find the Table in Image**

I am conducting research on 2 groups and lets call them A and B and these 2 groups are 2 Variables of my dataset. These are categorical data.. Below is sample of my data.

[image]

Now I want to know if group A is better than group B..

Using ChiSquare test of Independence I can know if there is any significant difference between these 2 groups. But how can I find which group is better than the other? Which Test I need to perform?

Comment: What do these counts represent?

Comment: It depends what you mean by better. And given that it would be important to know what the data means. Do you want a higher average? Do you want one to be more consistent than the other?

Comment: @DemetriPananos Hi, I have edited my post with picture of table..

Comment: @ajax2112 Hi, The data is of the deaths and survived counts of two Groups A and B subjected to certain expirements A and B respectively. I want to know based on this data, which Group is significantly better in terms of Survivals?

Comment: Group A has the higher observed survival rate. Your significant $\chi^2$ test says that the observed difference in survival rates groups A and B is unlikely if the survival rates are the same. In that case, the observed difference is exceptionally unlikely if B in fact has the higher survival rate. With the usual caveats about p-values, you would doubt that B has even as high of a survival rate, let alone an even higher survival rate.

Comment: @Dave I am proposing the same methodolgy as well.. But I am wondering If I can use 2 sample proportion z test with H0: proportion of A = proportion of B and HA: proportion of A > proportion of B

Comment: That sounds like a fine approach.